# How to show ruby garbage collection settings configured via the environment variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, garbage-collection

ruby has some environment variables to configure garbage collection.
However, I do not know that the environment variables really have affected to ruby run-time.
How do I confirm them?
In my understanding, GC.stats show statistics but it does not show and correspond to environment variable values.
My purpose is to activate GC more frequently that means I want to reduce memory usage.

module GC
https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.3.0/GC.html

e.g)

```
RUBY_GC_HEAP_INIT_SLOTS
RUBY_GC_HEAP_FREE_SLOTS
RUBY_GC_HEAP_GROWTH_FACTOR
RUBY_GC_HEAP_GROWTH_MAX_SLOTS
RUBY_GC_HEAP_OLDOBJECT_LIMIT_FACTOR
RUBY_GC_HEAP_OLDOBJECT_LIMIT_FACTOR
RUBY_GC_MALLOC_LIMIT
RUBY_GC_MALLOC_LIMIT_MAX
RUBY_GC_MALLOC_LIMIT_GROWTH_FACTOR
RUBY_GC_OLDMALLOC_LIMIT
RUBY_GC_OLDMALLOC_LIMIT_MAX
RUBY_GC_OLDMALLOC_LIMIT_GROWTH_FACTOR
```

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect `ENV` in the running process.

Beyond that, I don't know how you would verify that the env vars you set actually did anything.